# Converting a column of data to 3 columns of data - Matlab

Tags: matlab

Using the following, I have imported a .txt file:

```
[filename_input, pathname] = uigetfile('*.txt','Select .txt file');
if isequal(filename_input,0)
   disp('User selected Cancel')
else
   disp(['User selected ', fullfile(pathname, filename_input)])
end

M = csvread(filename_input);
```

I now have a single column of data. This is stored as doubles in Matlab. I would like this to be formatted as 3 columns, is there a way to get this into three columns instead of one?

Entries 1,4,7,10, etc. will become the new 1,2,3,4,etc. in column 1, entries 2,5,8,11,etc. will become the new 1,2,3,4,etc. in column 2, same idea for column 3.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: `reshape(M,3,[]).'` should do it.

Comment: While it is a duplicate of the linked question, @Divakar's `[]` syntax trick (explained in [the documentation for `reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)) is handy here.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly (didn't know the terminology for what to ask initially, Reshape Vector).